# Sorting array of objects using time and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I want to sort my array of objects in order from earliest to latest in time. I used the momentjs library to do this at first and it worked, but the method I was using is now deprecated.

At first I tried making the input time into a standard time(ex: 0500) and then sort it using that property. But I had trouble pushing this new standard time and all the other properties into the plans array.

I was thinking of using `array.sort()`  and sort it first by `am/pm` and then by number. I'm not sure how to go about it since I have to deal with `am` and `pm`

app.js

```
.controller('SchedulerController', schedulerCtrl);

    function schedulerCtrl() {
        this.plans = [
        {
            displayTime: '05:00pm',
            duration: '30',
            task: 'Team meeting',
        },
        {
            displayTime: '06:00pm',
            duration: '60',
            task: 'Watch favorite TV show'
        }
        ];
    }
    schedulerCtrl.prototype.addNewTask = function() {
        var that = this;
        that.plans.push(that.user);
        that.user = '';

}
```

Comment: Angular also provides [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for sorting.  You'd still have to write the ordering function and deal with the time strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom filter can be used ,

```
<p>{{item | orderBy:sortItemsAccording2Time}}</p>


var App = Angular.module('myApp',[])
 App.filter('sortItemsAccording2Time',function(input,scope){
    //logic here  (service dependency can also be used for orderby service by just injecting the respective service which serves the job)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) for an efficient [sorting](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy).

```
schedulerCtrl.prototype.addNewTask = function() {
        var that = this;
        that.plans.push(that.user);
        _.sortBy(that.plans, function (item) { return item.displayTime });
        that.user = '';

}
```